# Loop not Incrementing

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

So to give some context. I'm creating a little minesweeper problem that solves itself. I'm starting with an extremely basic algorithm at first, which is going to go through and when it sees a '-' character it's going to take a guess at the spot. Yes I know that is horrible, but I'm going to advance it soon.

But here is my issue.

**input**

```
public int[] aiMove()
{
    int[] move = new int[2];
    for(int a = 0; a<board.length-1; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b<board.length-1; b++)
        {
            System.out.println(a +" and "+ b);
            System.out.println(a+"<"+(board.length-1));
            System.out.println(b+"<"+(board.length-1));



            if(board[a][b]=='-')
            {
                move[0]=a;
                move[1]=b;
                return move;
            }
            else
            {

                System.out.println("No Moves left");
            }
        }
    }
    return move;
}
```

For some reason it doesn't want to increment the a and b values.

It's breaking into an infinite loop, so I did a quick check with those print statements in the code.

**And this is what was returned.**

```
 0<7
0 and 0
0<7
0<7
0 and 0
0<7
0<7
0 and 0
0<7
0<7
0 and 0
0<7
0<7
0 and 0
0<7
0<7
0 and 0
0<7
0<7
0 and 0
0<7
0<7
```

Comment: Perhaps you have an infinite loop that calls this method? Seems like it always returns a certain move and then is just called again. Can you post the code that calls this method?

Comment: It doesn't print `"No moves left"`? Perhaps it always immediately returns a move, but the infinite loop is called somewhere else.

Comment: Doesn't even print that, I found that it thinks there's no moves when there are still moves. But, that's something else that I found.

Comment: @Sparta board.length. Board is a 2d in array, the board is square. So either will work.

Comment: let me guess: board[0][0]=='-' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time this method is called it goes through this:

```
       if(board[a][b]=='-')
        {
            move[0]=a;
            move[1]=b;
            return move;
```

and `aiMove` must be being called repeatedly from another method.

Comment: It is called repeatedly, but once it returns a move it's supposed to go to the next method. There's is no loop or anything, it should just go to the method and then change that value and any neighbor that doesn't have a mine. I thought it was that case too, but maybe something in the other method is stopping it from changing the value. I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be though.

Comment: The return is for some reason breaking the method, I adjusted it at first to see if it ever left the method. And it wasn't. I removed the return, and now it will actually keep going.

Answer (score 0):

Your method does not call `No Moves left`, therefore in this part of code

```
        if(board[a][b]=='-')
        {
            move[0]=a;
            move[1]=b;
            return move;
        }
        else
        {

            System.out.println("No Moves left");
        }
```

Everytime these three lines are executed and by returning "move" the method ends

```
            move[0]=a;
            move[1]=b;
            return move;
```

Because your `board[0][0]` is equal to `-`, even when you call it several times, it always ends in first cycle, therefore it does not cycle anymore.